# Visible altitude across a raster from a point

Tags: raster, grass-gis, visibility

I have a raster surface model and I'm trying to determine the height an object would need to be at to be visible from an arbitrary point at an arbitrary altitude.

I am currently using Grass and have tried r.viewshed, while it does seem to be able to generate an elevation delta between the raster and the observer, I do not see a way to generate a delta between the raster and the line of sight at every point. my expectation is that everything that is directly visible would have a value of 0, and then shadowed areas would indicate the  minimum height an object would be visible at.

While I am using GRASS at the moment, I am not against considering another piece of software.

Anybody have any ideas? or am I going to have to pull the source for viewshed and modify it?

Comment: If not possible, you can also open an enhancement ticket at http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/

Comment: Hello, I am looking for a solution to the same problem. Have you found an efficient solution?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could achieve that with [`r.los`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.los.html). You could set different heights and see if there is a visibility.

```bash
r.los elevation.dem out=los.025 coord=598869,4916642 obs_elev=25 max_dist=1000
r.los elevation.dem out=los.050 coord=598869,4916642 obs_elev=50 max_dist=1000
r.los elevation.dem out=los.100 coord=598869,4916642 obs_elev=100 max_dist=1000
```

[`r.los`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.los.html) will return the vertical angle in degrees and make sure that you set the `max_dist` to the distance you need to speed up the process.

Comment: This might work, although it would be extremely slow. You also need to post-process the results to compute the threshold height at the cell that would make an object visible.